# Primefaces mobile render kit with client side validation doesn't work

Tags: java, client-side-validation, primefaces-mobile

I'm developing a mobile web app with Primefaces and want to integrate a client side validation but it doesn't work. It seems that the mobile render kit is not compatible with it or maybe I forgot to do something. Could anyone help me ? Thank you in advance.

The problem is when I use :

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.CLIENT_SIDE_VALIDATION</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

AND

```
<default-render-kit-id>PRIMEFACES_MOBILE</default-render-kit-id>
```

AND

```
validateClient="true" attribute,
```

client side validation script is not called and the page is automatically refreshed after I click the commandButton even if ajax is enabled.

In the web browser I have this java script error once a page is loaded :

> validators.js;jsessionid=1409a4a5b3f93be1b8d3134bfcce:1 Uncaught
>   TypeError: Cannot set property 'custom.emailValidator' of undefined
>       at validators.js;jsessionid=1409a4a5b3f93be1b8d3134bfcce:1

ALL WORKS FINE WITHOUT ANY ERRORS  when I remove PRIMEFACES_MOBILE

This is my sign_in.xhtml : (for the javascript and EmailValidator I copied example code from the Primefaces Showcase)

I also included multiple pm:pages in one page.

```
<ui:composition  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                 xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                 xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                 xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
                 xmlns:pm="http://primefaces.org/mobile"
                 xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">

    <pm:page id="sign_in">
        <pm:content>
            <h1 id="kie_title" align="center">KIE</h1>

            <h:form id="form_sign_in">
                <p:messages id="messages" autoUpdate="true" globalOnly="true"/>

                <pm:field>
                    <p:panelGrid columns="1">
                        <p:outputLabel for="email" value="Email"/>
                        <p:inputText id="email" value="#{signInCtrl.email}" required="true">
                            <!--<f:validateRegex pattern="[a-zA-Z]*"/>-->
                            <f:validator validatorId="custom.emailValidator"/>
                        </p:inputText>
                        <p:message for="email"/>
                    </p:panelGrid>
                </pm:field>

                <pm:field>
                    <p:panelGrid columns="1">
                        <p:outputLabel for="password" value="Password"/>
                        <p:password id="password" value="#{signInCtrl.password}" required="true"/>
                    </p:panelGrid>
                    <p:message for="password"/>
                </pm:field>

                <p:commandButton id="cmdbtn_sign_in" value="Sign In" action="#{signInCtrl.signIn()}" validateClient="true" 
                                 update="@form"/>
            </h:form>
        </pm:content>

        <!--Block fixed to the bottom of the page with New user and Forgot password links-->
        <div id="new_user">
            <p:button outcome="pm:sign_up?transition=slide" value="Sign Up"/>
            <p:link outcome="pm:password_recovery?transition=slide" value="Forgot your password ?"/>
        </div>
    </pm:page>
</ui:composition>
```